# remove all custom post created

Tags: posts, wpdb

i will automatically create a lot of post with the wp_insert_post function

```
<?php wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error ); ?>
```

all those custom post type will be call "house" and then after some testing, i what all those post and the revision to be deleted, to clear and clean the DB... so how i do that ?

i do all my request with $wpdb what is the query to delete/remove all post_type = house and there revision ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating posts directly in database is rarely good idea, since it skips all the APIs, hooks and so on that normally participate in the process.

You should use [`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/) to retrieve the list and [`wp_delete_post()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_delete_post/) for deletion to ensure it is done properly and there are no leftovers.

Comment: i will take good advices from anywhere, because when you think YOUR way to do this is the good way, it's always good to have another point of view.... thanks